# カメラ撮影が終わったことを検知する

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

`UIImagePickerController`を使ってカメラを実装したのですが、カメラ撮影が終わったことを検知するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？`UIImagePickerController`ではできないのでしょうか？試しに以下のサイトの「AVCaptureStillImageOutputを使用する方法」という記事を参考に組んでみるとカメラ撮影が終わったことを検知できるようになったのですが、iOSのデフォルトのカメラUIではなくなってしまいました。
http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/ios-camera-intro/

できればデフォルトのカメラを使いたいので`UIImagePickerController`で実装したいのですが、可能でしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

UIImagePickerControllerDelegateプロトコルを実装し、
- imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:メソッドを使えば可能です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご提示くださったメソッドを実装してみたのですが、didFinishPickingMediaWithInfoメソッドは呼ばれませんでした。。。UIImagePickerControllerDelegateプロトコルは実装し、imagePickerController.delegate = self; としているのですが、うまくいきませんでした。他に何か設定することがあるのでしょうか？